# Android layout include no layout

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app, portrait would have a `Button` where landscape would **NOT** have a `Button`, so I use `<include>` and did this:

layout/activity_main.xml

```
...
<include layout="@layout/my_button" />
...
```

values/layout.xml

```
...
<item name="my_button" type="layout">@layout/my_button_layout</item>
...
```

values-land/layout.xml

```
....
<item name="my_button" type="layout">@layout/empty_layout</item>
```

layout/my_button_layout.xml

```
...
<Button...... <!-- my button XML -->
...
```

layout/empty_layout.xml

```
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:visibility="gone" />
```

Now, this works, but I don't quite like the idea of having an useless view whenever the app's in landscape.

I tried to do:

```
<item name="my_button" type="layout">@null</item>
```

but this would throw a `ResourceNotFound` Exception

Is there a way around this?

(Yes I know I can do this programmatically, but then it defeats the purpose of Android's layout system)

Comment: Put two different layouts with the same name in layout-port and layout-land folders in your res folder.

Comment: I.tried that before, basically I will have to copy the entire layout to the layout-port directory and remove that small XML section of my Button. This is not quite future proof...

Comment: Put a boolean in your values-port and values-land folder then.

Comment: to control what? visibility?

Comment: Yes. You can add android:visibility tag to your layouts Button element with boolean values added to the two folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use two styles. One in an xml file in a portrait folder and the other in another xml file in the landscape folder. These styles could then set `android:visibility="gone"` and `android:visibility="visible"` then just set the style onto the button using `style="@style/MyButtonStyle"`

Comment: Sorry. I didn't explain myself fully. Replace the include with the raw button object. Then do the styling I explained above :) as the styling will do all the hiding you won't need the include anymore. Just a regular button that is set to gone when styled for landscape screens

Comment: Even though it didn't answer my question fully, I like the idea of using style